# Build Calendar into iOS App

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, xcode4

I am building a iPad app that will have a calendar and that calendar will pull down its events from CalDav or from .ics.

Does anyone know of any sample code that shows the basic structure on how to do this. Is their a Calendar controller already in xCode?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TapKu Library.It may be helpful .

http://developinginthedark.com/posts/iphone-tapku-calendar-markers

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about CalDav of .ics but you can access the calendar using the Event Kit (from iOS 4.0).  It lets you query and create calendar entries and suchlike.

[You can read about it here on the Apple site.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765)